# How to average the values of different files and save them in a new file

Tags: shell, awk

I have about 140 files with data which I would like to process with a script.

The files have two types of names:

1. `sys-time-4-16-80-15-1-1.txt`
2. `known-ratio-4-16-80-15-1-1.txt`

where the two last numbers vary. The penultimate number takes 1, 50, 100, 150,...,300, and the last number ranges from 1,2,3,4,5...,10. A sample of these files are in this [*link*](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2ynwbqw8301d27z/AACf3wemQWtC8c2AJ55M2LGDa?dl=0).

I would like to write a new file with 3 columns as follows:

A 1st column with the penultimate number of the file, i.e., 1,25,50...
A 2nd column with the mean value of the second column in each `sys-time-..` file.
A 3rd column with the mean value of the second column in each `known-ratio-..` file.

The result might have a row for each pair of averaged `2nd columns` of `sys` and `known` files:

```
1    mean-sys-1 mean-know-1
1    mean-sys-2 mean-know-2
.
.
1    mean-sys-10 mean-know-10
50   mean-sys-1  mean-know-1
50   mean-sys-2  mean-know-2
.
.
50   mean-sys-10 mean-know-10
100  mean-sys-1  mean-know-1
100  mean-sys-2  mean-know-2
.
.
100  mean-sys-10 mean-know-10
....
....
300  mean-sys-10 mean-know-10
```

where each row corresponds with the `sys` and `known` files with the same two last numbers.
Besides, I would like to copy in the first column the penultimate number of the files.

I know how to compute the mean value of the second column of a file with `awk`:

```
awk '{ sum += $2; n++ } END { if (n > 0) print sum / n; }' sys-time-4-16-80-15-1-5.txt
```

but I do not know how to iterate on all the files and build a result file with the three columns as above.

Comment: @vintnes You are right. The link has penultimate values 1, 50, 100, 150, 200 in the names. The example above is just a short sample of files. I would like to run the script in all the files of the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shell script that uses [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) to compute the averages (Though you can easily swap out to awk if desired; I prefer datamash for calculating stats):

```
#!/bin/sh

nums=$(mktemp)
sysmeans=$(mktemp)
knownmeans=$(mktemp)

for systime in sys-time-*.txt
do
    knownratio=$(echo -n "$systime" | sed -e 's/sys-time/known-ratio/')
    echo "$systime" | sed -E 's/.*-([0-9]+)-[0-9]+\.txt/\1/' >> "$nums"
    datamash -W mean 2 < "$systime" >> "$sysmeans"
    datamash -W mean 2 < "$knownratio" >> "$knownmeans"
done

paste "$nums" "$sysmeans" "$knownmeans"
rm -f "$nums" "$sysmeans" "$knownmeans"
```

It creates three temporary files, one per column, and after populating them with the data from each pair of files, one pair per line of each, uses `paste` to combine them all and print the result to standard output.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about `datamash`. May I ask you how could I change the script to use the files (have the same names) from two different folders.

Comment: @user1993416 The `basename` command would be useful for that.

Answer (score 1):

I've used GNU Awk for easy, per-file operations. This is untested; please let me know how it runs. You might want to look into `printf()` for pretty-printed output.

```
mapfile -t Files < <(find . -type f -name "*-4-16-80-15-*" |sort -t\- -k7,7 -k8,8)  #1
gawk '
  BEGINFILE {n=split(FILENAME, f, "-"); type=f[1]; a[type]=0}                    #2
            {a[type] = ($2 + a[type] * c++) / c}                                 #3
  ENDFILE   {if(type=="sys") print f[n], a[sys], a[known]}                       #4
' "${Files[@]}"
```

1. Create a Bash array with matching files sorted by the last two "keys". We will feed this array to Awk later. Notice how we alternate between "sys" and "known" files in this sample:

```
./known-ratio-4-16-80-15-2-150
./sys-time-4-16-80-15-2-150
./known-ratio-4-16-80-15-3-1
./sys-time-4-16-80-15-3-1
./known-ratio-4-16-80-15-3-50
./sys-time-4-16-80-15-3-50
```

2. At the beginning of every file, clear any existing average value and save the type as either "sys" or "known".
3. On every line, calculate the [Cumulative Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Cumulative_moving_average)
4. At the end of every file, check the file type. If we just handled a "sys" file, print the last part of the filename followed by our averages.